# get json content from a website with python

Tags: python, json, parsing

I have to get json's contents from a site and parsing them with python. I wrote this code :

```
import requests
import codecs
import urllib
import urllib3
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json

url = "http://opendata.arpa.emr.it/services/arkiweb/datasets/"

response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(response.read())
print(data)
```

I have this error : "the json object must be str, not 'bytes'". I don't know how to continue my script, any ideas?

Comment: I forget to add my imports! You're right!

Comment: Well, if you imported requests, then why use urllib?

Comment: There is a skill you need to learn: Google the error message!

Comment: I tried a lot of ways and I forget to delete older imports, you're right but the problem isn't in that section

Answer (score 0):

you have already imported requests (this module can deal with it)

```
response = requests.get("http://opendata.arpa.emr.it/services/arkiweb/datasets/")
a_dict = json.loads(response.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
import urllib, json
url = "http://opendata.arpa.emr.it/services/arkiweb/datasets/"
response = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(response.read())
print data
```